# EU Cookie Directive

Tags: facebook, cookies

With the new EU Cookie directive coming into place (http://www.cookielaw.org) I want to find out what the situation is with Facebook Applications/Tabs because it's a bit of a grey area.

As Facebook makes use of cookies as part of the authentication process in Apps and in many other ways too, is it Facebook's responsibility to show the user a message asking them to optin?

Advice on this from Facebook would be very useful.

Thanks

Comment: "because it's a bit of a grey area" - I think you meant *"it's a giant mess."*

Answer (score 0):

Where a site would work without a cookie being set, that cookie is relevant to the cookie law.

Where a site would break or functionality would no longer work when the cookie is not set, that cookie is exempt. e.g. login cookies.

As far as responsibility is concerned, that's something that hasn't been determined by case yet. Facebook sets the cookies yes, and though you cant prevent it, you did have the choice to use or not to use it, which it could be argued is the same thing as setting them yourself.

**Where responsibility is concerned, I advise you consult a relevant lawyer rather than persisting in that line of questioning here**

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the users land on **your** website, it's your responsibility to tell them about all cookies that are set both by the website and any other related web services you are using - including Facebook.

In most cases you should be fine with a list of cookies announced on a visible part of the website (on the top, not neccesarily with an annoying pop-up), [listing all cookies](https://webcookies.org/) and briefly explaining their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For my sites, I display a prompt simply by this script:

```
<script async src="https://www.cookie.eu/script.js"></script>
```